# How do I solve this odd puzzle?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, alphametic

I need help. Try to solve this puzzle. It's a blend of mathematics and words. The goal of word math problems is to assign each letter an integer value, 0-9. An example is below.

Example:

```
MAKE + KEYS = PSST
```

In this example: `E = 3`, `K = 1`, `A = 4`, `Y = 5`, `S = 7`, `T = 0`, `M = 8`, and `P = 9`.

When you use the integers for each variable, the math should work out correctly!
 The integers can not be used for 2 different letters, only one for one letter.

Real Problem: `IDIOT x HEM = WORMHOLE` (the `x` here denotes multiplication)

Comment: There is a solution for sure but I'm not sure what it is. My teacher didn't give me many hints. And yes you can use 0 in a letter.

Comment: I tried making a script to bruteforce this as well, but can't find any solution where each digit 0-9 maps into a single letter. Are you sure there is a solution?

Comment: Did you copy and paste this from the teacher's instructions? Or did you transcribe it, and if so, was it from handwritten or typed source? I'm trying to rule out trickery such as misleading use of numeral one and capital ell, or zero versus oh.

Comment: I know I'm a little late but I bruteforced and did not find a solution either.

Comment: answer this by prove it mathematically that this alphametic has no solution.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya I'm pretty sure a python program bashing it is sufficiently mathematical. I mean, there are computer assisted proofs out there (e.g pythagorean triples colouring problem or the more famous four colour theorem)

Comment: @Wen1now : Yes I know that, but to get upvotes, someone can prove it here. I am too lazy to do that.

Comment: But i already answered this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546757/how-do-you-substitute-integers-0-9-in-this-equation-to-solve-it)!!.. And my answer was that there are... no possible answer!!

Comment: @OompaLoompa See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How do you substitute integers 0-9 in this equation to solve it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2546757/377316). I've also confirmed @hyprfrcb's answer there (though my pride obeys me to mention that my python code runs in about 20 secs rather than minutes)

Comment: @hyprfrcb: When I asked my teacher if this is how you format it he said and I quote,"No you idiot". He said that I should format it like the problem above. When I tried to make a new problem I got replies saying that I should put it on this particular section of the website. So that's why there's a duplicate.

Comment: @shoover: My teacher typed up the instructions and I paraphrased it. I left all the critical parts in. I've double checked for the "misleading use of numeral one and capital ell, or zero versus oh" and have concluded that everything is fine.

Comment: @Everyone: There is a solution. I've asked my teacher about it 16 times in a row.

Comment: @OompaLoompa Both hypr and me have written a program which checks ALL permutations which are valid according to your description. Both of our programs confirm that a difference of 7 is the closest you can get if no two letters can have the same value (if they can, just assign 0 to every letter and it works fine). If your teacher keeps insisting there is a solution, it must be a lateral-thinking one.

Comment: Speaking of 16 times: you could do the alphametic in base 16: 8B843₁₆ × 257₁₆ = 146724C5₁₆.

Comment: My point was that it's possible that the teacher has used trickery, and one or more of the "letter oh" characters are actually hardcoded zeros, while the remaining "letter oh" characters represent some other digit, and some other letter represents zero. For example, if `wormhole` is actually `w0rmhole` or `wormh0le`, and `o=2` and `m=0`, or something like that. Ditto with the "letter eye" or "letter ell" and the digit "one".

Comment: when you figure this out by asking the teacher... please let us know the response.

Comment: I think the question in here is fully valid, even adviced in people from MSE, until the puzzle became *truly* solved :). And this is a real life puzzle guys....

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of these kinds of puzzles here, in the [alphametic](/questions/tagged/alphametic) tag. As for how to solve them, it's a matter of noticing relationships to rule out certain values, then trial and error, choosing values until you get a contradiction.

Take your simpler `MAKE + KEYS = PSST` example. Since there is no "carry", M and K must total 9 or less, which rules out them both being 5 or above, and later, when you know one of them, puts upper bounds on the other. It also constrains P: if they are 4 and 5, P is 9. If they were 1 and 0, P would be 1, but can't be. So you can rule out P being 1 or 0 (two different positive numbers can't add to zero.)

Some people actually write out equations:

```
E + S = T or T + 10
K + Y (+ maybe 1) = S or S + 10
```

Then they either solve simultaneous equations or just plug in some guesses.

The multiplying one is harder, and uses different relationships. So you know that

```
T * M = E + 10 or 20 or ....
```

And then there are things like "ah that means this letter must be odd" to help continue to narrow down the field.

You mentioned a teacher; are you expected to write a program to do this, or do it by hand?

Comment: "[...], M and K must both be 5 or less" Surely 1+8 also produces no carry (assuming A+E<10).

Comment: you're right, edited

Comment: +1 on how are you expected to do this.  It isn't an easy one by hand at all. (I just found people have determined that this has no solution. Something is off here.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this beautiful nested-loop approach:

```
  // IDIOT x HEM = WORMHOLE
var idiot = "00000"
var hem = "000";
var wormhole = "00000000";
var permuation_check ="";

// "IDOTHEMWRL"; // all used chars, but duplicates removed.
{



calculateStuff = function()
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log("1 i : " + i);
      for (var d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
          for (var o = 0; o < 10; o++) {
              for (var t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
                  console.log("t : " + t);
                  for (var h = 0; h < 10; h++) {
                      for (var e = 0; e < 10; e++) {
                          for (var m = 0; m < 10; m++) {
                              for (var w = 0; w < 10; w++) {
                                  for (var r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
                                      for (var l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
                                          permutation_check = ""+i+d+o+t+h+e+m+w+r+l;
                                          idiot = parseInt("" + i + d + i + o + t);
                                          hem = parseInt("" + h + e + m);
                                          wormhole = parseInt("" + w + o + r + m + h + o + l + e);

                                          if(permutation_check.indexOf(""+i) != 0 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+d) != 1 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+o) != 2 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+t) != 3 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+h) != 4 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+e) != 5 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+m) != 6 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+w) != 7 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+r) != 8 &&
                                              permutation_check.indexOf(""+l) != 9)
                                                 {
                                                if (idiot * hem == wormhole) {
                                                    console.log("found : " + idiot + " x " + hem + " = " + wormhole);
                                                    alert("found : " + idiot + " x " + hem + " = " + wormhole);
                                                }
                                          }                                          
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      console.log("i : " + i);
  }

}
```

It didn't find a solution. Can Letters get bigger than 9 or negative?

also, if you add all letters and remove duplicates, you get : "IDOTHEMWRL" -> "I DO THEM WRL" - is this a hidden joke maybe?

Comment: Oh god, the nested loops hurt my eyes. Isn't there some kind of permutation library for js you can use?

Comment: I disagree in the "beautiful" part. Beautiness, it seems, is not without a sense of relativity.

Comment: Why the heck the phrase "I DO THEM WRL" appeared there???

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to check every permutation in accordance with your rules. There are 105 solutions for your example, but 0 solutions for your actual question. It is not solvable.